# the css selector :empty for tr is not working

Tags: html, css

I have HTML code that is generated from a legacy Asp.net Application. it generates few empty `tr` inside a table like this

```
<table>
 <tr> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
   <td> Text here</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

MY CSS code

```
  tr:empty{
    display:none;
  }
```

In css i want to hide empty `tr`

I have used `:empty` selector but it is not working. 
Please note that technically tr is not empty. in DOM it is printing like this

```
  <tr>
  </tr>
```

Which means tr has a line break or some characters in it.

Can anyone suggest me a better approach to fix this issue.

Note: i cannot modify HTML in any way. I cannot add Classes, or Ids due to code limitations. 
Also i cannot write java-script to the code. I can only write CSS.

Comment: Please provide your css code.

Comment: table {  empty-cells: hide; } ???

Comment: because it's not empty ... empty is `<tr></tr>` and not `<tr> </tr>`

Comment: @Roy it is not working. I have tried it several times.

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes I know, This HTML is generated from a backend code and we don't have access to change or modify backend code. We need to handle this in the current scenario

Comment: @JoykalInfotech plz check again, CSS code is in the description. Thank  you

Comment: Please note that `tr` can only have `td`,  `tr`, `script` and `template` children. Specifically, it cannot have `textNode` children, which I assume is the reason `tr:empty` won't work.